# about the proof of Hurwitz theorem in Lawler's book

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Here is the proof from Lawler's book Conformally Invariant Processes in the Plane:

[image]

My question is that in the line of equation, why the condition of the lemma can imply the limit commute with integration and differentiation? Thanks.

Comment: [This section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability) and the one following.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy But in the assumption of lemma, there is no condition about the uniform convergence of the function series.

Comment: You can assume it, prove the theorem in that case, and then get the theorem without it by passing to a subsequence that does converge uniformly on compact subsets of $D$. The existence of such a sequence is not an obvious step. For example, you could use [Montel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem). I don't know if they have some theorem around this in that books that allows them to omit the argument, but it looks like an oversight.